# Can I use MAX/MSP code to make an iOS app?

Tags: juce, max-msp-jitter

I'm using MAX/MSP for audio signal processing. I want to use the same processing in an iOS app. Can I do that?

Comment: not really. but  you could port your code to PD, to make it work with the libPD on iOS for apps who are taking advantage of it. Mobmuplat and co..  But your question was asked before.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281616/porting-max-msp-app-to-ios?rq=1

Comment: if you know how to juce, you are much better in the game when you just code it in C,C++ with it.

Answer (score 1):

Cycling '74 has a video outline of how to setup your Max/Msp ~gen project in a way that lets you export to C++ for use in Juce. Juce can then be used to build the UI and iOS app that talks to your signal processing code.  There are two example projects.

First:

- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f94Go5Qafg8
- Github: https://github.com/Cycling74/gen-plugin-export

Second:

- Github: https://github.com/Cycling74/gen-workshop

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to with the new RNBO update

Answer (score 0):

Check out SwiftRNBO:
https://github.com/ceammc/SwiftRNBO

There is an example project that uses RNBO.